# emails by sendgrid in a loop sending only one

Tags: php, email, html-email, sendgrid

I am sending email to all of my recents members who have not verified their emails by sndgrid email api

the process has a loop of about 56 members may be less also
here is the code

```
    $getall_NOW_joins=mysqli_query($connection,"select name,email from members
    where (some code) order by id desc limit 53");
     while($theEMAILS=mysqli_fetch_array($getall_NOW_joins)){
      $EMAILesee=$theEMAILS['email'];
    $messageto90="<body>some html...... </body>"
          $subject09="Verify email - domain";
        $json_string = array( 'to' => array("$EMAILesee"),'category' => 'cron_rec_m');
       $tos=$EMAILesee;
       include_once('emailapi.php');
       echo $response."<br/>";
        }
```

the page emailapi contains

```
  <?php

    $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
   $user = 'some';
     $pass = 'thing';
   $params = array(
  'api_user'  => $user,
  'api_key'   => $pass,
  'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
'to'        => "$tos",
'subject'   => "$subject09",
'html'      => "$messageto90",
'from'      => "domain.com<contact@domain.com>",
 );


  $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
     $session = curl_init($request);
   // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
   curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
   // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   // Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   // obtain response
      $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    ?>
```

THE problem is the page sends only one email which is the first one in loop other emails are not sent please help me find the bug
I am using this page in cron job

Comment: The include_once() thing doesn't matter. You are missing a semicolon after   $messageto90="<body>some html...... </body>" line.

Comment: sorry buddy i missed it here but in the real page it is mentioned ..

Comment: @bassxzero of course it matters. What do you think `include_once` does?

Comment: @rjdown it is an guard that basically checks to see if the file has already been included once. If it has not then it gets added. If it has already been included then nothing happens. include_once and require_once are different.

Comment: @bassxzero exactly, so if the code that sends the email is in the included file... which is only included once... you can't really expect it to send more than one email.

Comment: @rjdown That's what i get for assuming that "emailapi" was an API or set of functions. Instead "emailapi" was some code. Ignore my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you're using `include_once('emailapi.php');`. Change it to `include`.